CPU ressource is full with multiple LemonLDAP Users
I have a LemonLDAP SSO server for my users authentication on my application (via mellon) with a DS389 LDAP server behind it.
I carry out performance shots with JMETER where I can reach 270 v-users.
However, it seems that CPU consumption increases with each connection without ever decreasing with disconnections. This ultimately causes a shutdown of the ns-slapd service killed by the JVM
Out of memory: Kill process 10550 (ns-slapd) score 48 or sacrifice child
Killed process 10550, UID 500, (ns-slapd) total-vm:3139484kB, anon-rss:241188kB, file-rss:240kB

With TOP, I see several httpd processes which each consume between 20% and 30% of the CPU
Do you know how to correct this phenomenon knowing that I increased the server resources (from 4 to 6 CPUs and from 4Gb to 6Gb of RAM)?
